# Count the data in a column which varies every time and return that count in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, count, assign

Im working with a lot of excel sheets. I need to count the rows for some columns and then assign that count to a cell most preferably the one right below the last cell with data on the column thats being counted.

I know how to count the cells and how to go to the cell below the cell with last data. I'm just having trouble assigning the value of the count to a cell. Thanks!

I used below to count

```
Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row
```

and the below to go to last cell

```
Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the `xlUp` method to find the last used cell instead of the `xlDown` method. The `xlDown` method will stop at the next empty cell below G1, so if there are blanks in your data column it will not find the very last used cell. Therefore you must use the `xlUp` method.

Then just use the value of the `LastRow` variable to write it into your desired cell.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

'so next free row is
ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, "G").Value = LastRow
```